# Is there a PDF parser for PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, parsing

Hi I know about several PDF *Generators* for php (fpdf, dompdf, etc.)
What I want to know is about a parser.

For reasons beyond my control, certain information I need is only in a table inside a pdf
and I need to extract that table and convert it to an array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am giving a bounty to anyone who can give us a working example on how to extract the text of a pdf. The solution has to use free libraries (no xPDF or PDF2Text) and platform independent (must work on win and unix, so no PDF2Text). It can use the exec() or shell() function of PHP.

Comment: Thanks Kau-Boy. Maybe a bounty will help motivate more detailed answers.

Comment: For reference, there is a better PDF parser here: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Answer (score 31):

I've written one before (for similar needs), and I can say this:  Have fun.  It's quite a complex task.  The [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) is large and unwieldy.  There are several methods of storing text inside of it.  And the kicker is that each PDF generator is different in how it works.  So while something like TFPDF or DOMPDF creates REALLY easy to read PDFs (from a machine standpoint), Acrobat makes some really hellish documents.

The reason is how it writes the text.  Most DOM based renderers --that I've used-- write the entire line as one string, and position it once (which is really easy to read).  Acrobat tries to be more efficient (and it is) by writing only one or maybe a few characters at a time, and positioning them independently.  While this REALLY simplifies rendering, it makes reading MUCH more difficult.

The up side here, is that the PDF format in itself is really simple.  You have "objects" that follow a regular syntax.  Then you can link them together to generate the content. The specification does a good job at describing the file format.  But real world reading is going to take a bit of brain power...

Some helpful pieces of advice that I had to learn the hard way if you're going to write it yourself:

1. Adobe likes to re-map fonts.  So character `65` will likely not be `A`...  You need to find a map object and deduce what it's doing based upon what characters are in there.  And it is efficient since if a character doesn't appear in the document for that font, it doesn't include it (which makes life difficult if you try to programmatically edit a PDF)...
2. Write it as abstract as possible.  Write classes for each object type, and each native type (strings, numbers, etc).  Let those classes parse for you.  There will be a fair bit of repetition in there, but you'll save yourself in the end when you realize that you need to tweak something for only one specific type)...
3. Write for a specific version or two of the PDF spec, and enforce it.  Check the version number, and if it's higher than you expect, bail...  And don't try to "make it work".  If you want to support newer versions, break out the specification and upgrade the parser from there.  Don't try to trial and error your way up (it's not fun)...
4. Good luck with compressed streams.  I've found that typically you can't trust the length arguments to verify what you are uncompressing.  Sometimes (for some generators) it works well...  Others it's off by one or more bytes.  I just attempt to deflate it if the filter matches, and then force the length...
5. When testing lengths, don't use `strlen`.  Use `mb_strlen($string, '8bit')` since it will compensate for different character sets (and allow potentially invalid characters in other charsets).

Otherwise, best of luck...

Comment: +1 I might even call it nightmareish.  The spec is huge, a PDF file almost resembles a filesystem with so many different options and choices within... you can certainly see how they can hide jail-breaking ability in there.

Comment: Would you expect anything less from Adobe?

Comment: @bpeterson76, yes.. I don't want my PDFs to be downloadable :(

Answer (score 17):

I use PDFBox for that (http://pdfbox.apache.org/). This software is javabased and platform independend. It works fast and reliable. You can use it via exec or shell execute or via a PHP/Java-Bridge (http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 3):

Have you already looked at [xPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) ?  There is a program in there called pdftotext that will do the conversion. You can call it from PHP and then read in the text version of the PDF. You will need to have the ability to run exec() or system() from php, so this may not work on all hosted solutions though.

Also, there are some examples on the [PHP site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php) that will convert PDF to text, although its pretty rough. You may want to try some of those examples as well. On that [PHP page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php), search for luc at phpt dot org.

Comment: I tried out xpdf based on your recommendation, and was surprised how well it works - thanks!

Comment: As of 2022-Jul-2, the links to the PHP site are 404 (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php ) and I can't find the equivalent page.

Answer (score 2):

[Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) is part of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).  Their manual states:

> The `Zend_Pdf` component is a PDF
>   (Portable Document Format)
>   manipulation engine. It can load,
>   create, modify and save documents.
>   Thus it can help any PHP application
>   dynamically create PDF documents by
>   modifying existing documents or
>   generating new ones from scratch.

Comment: +1 - Zend Framework components reliably do what they say they will.

Comment: I dont believe you can read text in PDF files using Zend_Pdf

Comment: Besides Zend_Pdf does not support PDF format > 1.4

Comment: @Marronsuisse, Yes, Zend_Pdf has gone fallow and received almost no updates since 2011.  In ZF2, it's been removed from the core distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GhostScript or ITextSharp, there are various cross-platform version of both.

Answer (score 1):

**[This](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/)** is PHP PDF parser, which exists in two flavours:

1. Free version can parse PDFs up to format PDF 1.5
2. Commercial add-on can parse any PDF format (up to current 1.9)

Comment: That link is dead, but I think this is a fork of it: https://github.com/mark9000/FPDI

Answer (score 0):

It may not actually be a table inside the PDF as the PDF loses that sort of information...