# How to modify a specific character in an existing XFA PDF?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, xfa

I'm stuck on a crazy project that has me looking for a strange solution. I've got a XFA PDF document generated by an outside party. There's are several checkmark characters '✓' on the PDF's that I need to simply change to 'X'. The reason for this is beyond my control. I'm just looking for a way to change the ✓'s into X's. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it possible?

Currently we use PHP and TCPDF for creating "our" server PDF's, but this particular PDF is generated outside of my control by a third party that doesn't want to alter their way of doing things. To make things worse, I don't know how many or where the checkmarks may exist. It's just one very specific character that is in need of changing. Does any know a way of hacking the document to change the character?

Character 2713

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Comment: *Can anyone point me in the right direction?* - Define *right* and define *Direction*, otherwise: Over there! / *Is it possible?* - Sure, it is possible  --- hint: Read the FAQ how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can. To my (rather limited) knowledge of the PDF format, you can only *reliably* search and replace strings of one character in length, since they are created by placing strings of variable length at specific co-ordinates, in an arbitrary order. The string 'hello' could therefore be one string of five letters, or five strings of one letter each or some combination thereof, all placed in the correct position (and in whatever order the print driver decided upon).

I'm afraid I don't know of any libraries that will do this, but I'd be surprised if they don't exist. You'll need to read PDF objects in, do the replacement, and write them out to a new file. I'd start off researching around the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php).

Edit: [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php) looks like it might be useful.