# Extracting text from PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I am using Imagick libraries to generate image from each PDF, although I need some way to get text out of each page too. Is there any option in Imagick or should I use another PHP library?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php

Comment: thanks adnan but none of those options seems to work. I already checked them

Comment: Have a look at this: http://php.livejournal.com/295413.html it might help you.