# Coordinates of images in PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, coordinates, fpdf

How do I get a coordinate (x,y) of an image from the PDF file using PHP?

For example, I have a PDF document page, I know the size of the page, there I have one image, I know its size too (because I've extracted it using the `pdfimages` tool). However, I need to know where was this image situated on the page.

I've read that it maybe could be done using FPDF but I couldn't understand how.

Comment: To get the coordinates of an item, I think you might have to parse the document at quite a low level. See this answer for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php

Answer (score 1):

To get PDF images with their coordinates, ImageData and size informations, you have to get PDFlib [You can get the PECL free version here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.setup.php) and TET (Text Extraction Toolkit) [here](http://www.pdflib.com/download/tet/).

After configuring PDFlib and TET and linking both of them to your php's extension on the php.ini (extension=pdf.so and extension=php_tet.so), you will have a bunch of examples in the directory where you installed PDFlib (where you typed ./configure && make && make install or where you get the "php_tet.so"). Open them to see how to use the functions. This lib is object oriented.

With it you can get all the images (coordinates, size and create a jpeg file) and texts (size, font and coordinates) of each pages of a PDF.

I'm at your service if you have other questions or if a point is not clear to you ;)

P.S Sorry my english is not very good

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you are a bit late :) But anyway I will keep it in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Haha np, but this solution is more optimized and with it you can create jpeg images from the PDF ;) It's very useful to extract images and text from a pdf and replace them on a webpage or an object ;)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to convert your `pdf` to an image (there are scripts available to do so, didn't try it but [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5846-PHP-Convert-PDF-documents-to-images-using-Ghostscript.html) might do the job)

Then you can use the code I posted on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345256/determine-position-of-one-image-in-another-with-php) to locate an image inside another image.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually why I asked that question ;) thanks again btw