# Parse PDF file, and read specific sections with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

I am looking for a library through which I can read my pdf file (which contain both images & text), and read the speicific information (customer information).

I have created the pdf file though html2pdf class. Now since I have not keep track of all the changes, I need to read the pdf file for some information.

My pdf structure is

```
 Header
 customer information
 Order details.
 footer
```

I want to read the Order details which are in a table with products & their prices.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: First you need to convert pdf to text. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php

Answer (score 0):

You can start from reading php pdf functions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php#53628

Or use some external library available out there:

http://www.pdfparser.org