# How to read pdf and extract text from pdf in symfony1.1?

Tags: symfony1

I am working on `Symfony-1.1` in an existing project. How can I read `pdf` files and extract text from them?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Symfony 1.1 related question, actually. It's a PHP one. There several libraries to handle PDFs in PHP. Following are some suggestions.

- https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser
- http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a
- http://www.pdflib.com/

If you just need to parse pdf in anyway and then process the text in PHP, you can also consider using a java library like the following.

- http://pdfbox.apache.org/ ([Is there a PDF parser for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php))

Comment: I have tried class.pdf2text.php and pdfparser. Since i am working on Indian languages scripts (UTF-8 text), class.pdf2text.php did not work for me. In pdfparser, we need to create a separate directory for vendor to import the pdfparser, and we are not permitted to create another directory inside the symfony-1.1/ directory. So I want to use the inbuilt libraries (if there are such libraries are in symfony-1.1 repo) in Symfony-1.1 to extract the text from PDF's.

Comment: I don't think there is such a library that's part of Symfony 1.1. :-/