# Extract editable pdf form fields with PdfParser?

Tags: javascript, php

We are developing PHP & MySQL based application. We distribute a registration form in PDF format. After filling form, user will upload PDF form to our application to register. We want to extract registration data in PDF form from PHP and save these data to database.  Can someone point me how can i do this task with PdfParser or any other PHP class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3626767/861704